# No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -101

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc

This is my code:

```
String q="select * from emp";
Query que  = em.createNativeQuery(q);
it is working fine but for 

String q="select * from dept";
```

I used a Annotation based mapping. But it results in this exception:

```
Hibernate: select  activity_id,accepted_on,resource_id, updated_date from case_assignment_history
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -101
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:630)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:75)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311)
    at $Proxy39.getResultList(Unknown Source)
    at com.quintiles.smsw.core.infrastructure.model.impl.AssignmentPersistent.getCaseHistory(AssignmentPersistent.java:2254)
    at com.quintiles.smsw.core.infrastructure.service.AssignmentService.GetCaseHistory(AssignmentService.java:1033)
    at com.quintiles.smsw.infrastructure.service.test.AssignmentServiceTest.testGetCaseHistory(AssignmentServiceTest.java:86)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:73)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:46)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:180)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:41)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:173)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -101
    at org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.getHibernateTypeName(Dialect.java:369)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader$Metadata.getHibernateType(CustomLoader.java:559)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader$ScalarResultColumnProcessor.performDiscovery(CustomLoader.java:485)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.autoDiscoverTypes(CustomLoader.java:501)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1787)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:662)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:224)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2211)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2095)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2090)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:289)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1695)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:142)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:66)
    ... 33 more
```

Comment: Are you using a persistence.xml to set your datasource? If so, you might want to try to set the Dialect, using
`<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />`
depending on your database. To check available dialects, go to :
[link](http://www.javabeat.net/list-of-hibernate-sql-dialects/).

Comment: This is missing the database and hibernate version used and your table schema.

Comment: actually i am using persistence.xml and it is woking fine for all other table but i have created  index on that table including 3 col may be due to   that it is causing this error ....if so what i need to do??

Answer (score 5):

If the table of column type has TIMESTAMP 
try like this:

> select cast(CREATED_TIMESTAMP as date) CREATED_TIMESTAMP from dept;

Use for all column type TIMESTAMP